# Ruby: How to show the character, decimal value, and hex value of each character in a string

Tags: ruby

How to show the character, decimal value, and hex value of each character in a string

```
"hello test test"
```

Comment: An example output would be good h10569e10064.. ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope this isn't homework? It's fine to ask for help with homework if you're stuck, but please don't ask for a complete solution: you won't learn anything unless you make some effort.

You need the `chars` iterator (or its alias `each_char`) like this

```
s = "hello test test"

s.chars do |c|
  puts "%s %3d %02X" % [ c, c.ord, c.ord ]
end
```

**output**

```
h 104 68
e 101 65
l 108 6C
l 108 6C
o 111 6F
   32 20
t 116 74
e 101 65
s 115 73
t 116 74
   32 20
t 116 74
e 101 65
s 115 73
t 116 74
```

Answer (score 0):

Each character use [String#chars](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-chars)

```
[72] pry(main)> "hello test test".chars
=> ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "t", "e", "s", "t", " ", "t", "e", "s", "t"]
```

Decimal value of each character use [String#ord](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-ord)

```
[73] pry(main)> "hello test test".chars.map(&:ord)
=> [104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 116, 101, 115, 116, 32, 116, 101, 115, 116]
```

`ASCII hex`

```
[84] pry(main)>"hello test test".chars.map { |x| x.ord.to_s(16) }
=> ["68","65","6c","6c","6f","20","74","65","73","74","20","74","65","73","74"]
```

Comment: Something a bit wrong with the hex version surely.

Comment: Because `to_i(16)` tries to convert characters like h, which is out of the range. `h` is 18th number (0-9 and a-f) which are converted to 0 by default. The same with `hex` I guess. ps. Taking English characters only.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson because some of the characters cannot be converted to and from `hex`, `hex` ranges from `0 to f`

Comment: Strangely enough I know what Hex is, which is why I was pretty sure a string of 0 and 14s didn't represent the characters in the string.

Comment: Wasn't me who marked you down by the way.

Answer (score 0):

```
'hello test test'.each_char { |c| puts "#{c} => #{c.hex} => #{c.ord}" }
```

Comment: String#hex dose not show hexadecimal value of a character. It converts hexadecimal string into the corresponding number. `'j'.hex == 0 `,
 `'0xAF'.hex == 175`.